# Keep img at the bottom of page

Tags: html, css, css-position

I know it's redundant question, but answers which I saw are unbelievable. Multiple lines for such easy task? No way.

I want to keep `img` at the end of page (not at the end of displayed screen - I have this issue now).

current, wrong code:

```
#footerimg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index:-2;
}
```

I need a situation, when I will not be able to see the image until I scroll at the bottom of page.

I can't believe that there is no such option in CSS like `bottom-page:0px`

EDIT:
[image: explanation photo for better understanding]

Comment: I dont get the question. maybe post a pic of what you want

Comment: I need a situation, when I will not be able to see the image until I scroll at the bottom of page.

Comment: What's wrong with position:absolute, like you have now?

Comment: That is at the bottom of displayed screen. When I scroll down I will not see the picture anymore. It won't be at the bottom of page.

Comment: did you try simply paste `<img>` tag just before closing tag `</body>`?

Comment: @Banzay - it could work, but I prefer solution via CSS. I need to put this img in each page ... but I will think about it. thanks!

Comment: it seems I understand you. I'll change my answer

Comment: Based on the rest of the markup your CSS might or might not do, so if you could post it too and we hopefully will be able to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Meet CSS [*`transform`*](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) property - apply `transform: translateY(100%)`.

See demo below:

```css
#footerimg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index:-2;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<img id="footerimg" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
```

**EDIT**:

Looking at the image added to the question, I think you don't need *positioning* - just put the img as the last element in the html markup.

A possible solution can be this:

```css
.content {
  height: 120vh;
}
section {
  text-align: right;
}
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<section class="content"></section>
<section>
  <img id="footerimg" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</section>
```

Comment: @user3160441 let me know your thoughts on this, thanks!

Comment: But it's pushing down the image by "1 screen" down (100%) . It's not sticking to the bottom of content.

Comment: try `position: fixed` and check? Is that the effect you are looking for?

Comment: see my update. your answer would be correct if the height of page would be exactly two times bigger then displayed area

Comment: @user3160441 check out the edit and let me know your feedback... a solution *without* positioning and using `text-align: right`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to define positioned relative block-level element at the end of body. This will create new block formatting context and all inside absolute positioned elements will be placed relatively to it.

Look at snippet example:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}
.blk1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: orange;
}
.blk2{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #9c9;
}
img.btm {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease; 
  
}
.blk2:hover .btm {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="blk1">
</div>
<div class="blk2">
<img src="//placehold.it/100/100" class="btm">
</div>
```

Here is another solution:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.blk1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vh;
  background: orange;
}
body:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('//placehold.it/100/100');
}
```

```html
<div class="blk1">
    </div>
```

So you can just add `position: relative` to `body` css styles

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

and add `body:after`:

```
body:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url('//placehold.it/100/100');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little bit making confusing me you mentioned in your question like that: "when I will not be able to see the image until I scroll at the bottom of page."

Then I think you do not need any effort you need just place image under footer container, when you will go bottom then you will be found at bottom of the page and this is very traditional way no need any tricky code for that.

Comment: What in situation if I have div from external HTML file and want to locate it by CSS? And such image would be in every page as a background image. Why I can easily put such img by CSS on the top page (or screen - the same - top:0px), but not at the bottom of page.